# msbuild fails on Certificate could not be opened, network password not correct

Tags: msbuild, pfx, appx, appxmanifest

I am trying to create a signed appx package as a test using a purchased code signing certificate.  I cannot get it to build without installing the cert locally first (which I don't want to do given this will be done in a CI/CD environment).

I am executing the following on a solution containing an empty WPF project and WAP project.

```
msbuild $Solution_Path /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x64" 
/p:AppxPackageDir=$App_Packages_Directory /p:AppxBundle=Never 
/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint=$myThumbprint 
/p:PackageCertificateKeyFile=$myCert /p:PackageCertificatePassword=$myPassword
```

error: Certificate could not be opened
error: The specified network password is not correct

I have confirmed the password of $myPassword and thumbprint is $myThumprint by importing the cert and verifying it.  I have also tried assigning "" to $myThumprint.  I have confirmed the location of $myCert

It will build if I assign AppxPackageSigningEnable=false, but it will be unusable as it is not signed.

In appxmanifest, I have assigned Identity/Publisher to the publisher id of the cert (e.g., Publisher="CN=John Doe, O=Acme, L=TheMoon, S=OuterSpace, C=Universe") and Properties/PublisherDisplayName = the cert's CN (=John Doe)

I have tried exporting the pfx into a cer and using that, but that fails on the cert is not usable as it doesn't include a private key.

I have tried exporting the pfx into a base64 string and then creating a pfx from that - still fails (desperate measures).

Any tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that a password protected cert needs to be stored in a cert store for msbuild to use it.  Therefore, I ignored the cert on build and added it later by doing the following:

1. Remove all signing parameters from msbuild as follows

```
msbuild $Solution_Path /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideLoadOnly /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x64" 
/p:AppxPackageDir=$App_Packages_Directory /p:AppxBundle=Never 
/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false
```

2. Given the name of the appx will change based on version and I couldn't find a way to pass wildcards to the SignTool, I used this to grab the built appx:

```
$Packages_2Sign = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $currentDirectory -Include *.appx).fullname
```

3. Finally, use the SignTool to sign the appx built from the prior step

```
SignTool sign /fd sha256 /a 
/f $certificatePath /p $certificatePwd $Packages_2Sign
```

Comment: To use SignTool on GitHub Actions, the path will need to be specified.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146751/how-to-sign-appx-msix-package-using-signtool-in-github-actions